# parsing xml with jquery

Tags: jquery, xml, parsing

I am querying the Microsoft Office SharePoint Server Search Service to write some results into a web part. I have the query working correctly but am having some trouble parsing the xml response via JQuery.

Below is the XML response :

```
<document>
<properties>
 <Property>
  <Name>p1</Name> 
  <Type>String</Type> 
  <Value>blue</Value> 
  </Property>
<Property>
  <Name>title</Name> 
  <Type>string</Type> 
  <Value>titreA</Value> 
  </Property>
  </properties>
</document>
<document>
<properties>
 <Property>
  <Name>p1</Name> 
  <Type>String</Type> 
  <Value>blue</Value> 
  </Property>
  <Property>
  <Name>title</Name> 
  <Type>string</Type> 
  <Value>titreB</Value> 
  </Property>
  </properties>
</document>
<document>
<properties>
 <Property>
  <Name>p1</Name> 
  <Type>String</Type> 
  <Value>green</Value> 
  </Property>
 <Property>
  <Name>title</Name> 
  <Type>string</Type> 
  <Value>titreC</Value> 
  </Property>
  </properties>
</document>
<document>
<properties>
 <Property>
  <Name>p1</Name> 
  <Type>String</Type> 
  <Value>red</Value> 
  </Property>
 <Property>
  <Name>title</Name> 
  <Type>string</Type> 
  <Value>titreD</Value> 
  </Property>
  </properties>
</document>
```

How can i retrieve p1 value, and number of occurence of this value ?
Like this : blue(2), green(1), red(1)

Comment: Please post the javascript you're using to parse the xml.

Comment: You're going to need to post the javascript that handles the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML data can be 'parsed' using jQuery's methods just like HTML.  Assuming `data` is the XML data.

```
var name = 'p1';
$data = $(data);
$p1 = $data.find('Name:contains("'+name+'")').parent('Property');
p1Value = $p1.map(function(i,v){
  return $(v).children('Value').text(); 
}).get();
alert(p1Value);
```

p1Value is an array of values that have a name of 'p1'.

`p1Value[0]` is equal to 'blue'.

If you also want the number of occurrences, you can do this.

```
var name = 'p1';
$data = $(data);
$p1 = $data.find('Name:contains("'+name+'")').parent('Property');
p1Values = {};
$p1.each(function(i,v){
  var val = $(v).children('Value').text();
  if(p1Values.hasOwnProperty(val)){
    p1Values[val]++;
  }
  else{
    p1Values[val] = 1;
  }
});
```

p1Values is an object with the value as the property name, and the occurrences as the property value.

`p1Value['blue']` is equal to 2.

Comment: seems to work like i want :) Really simple to understand. Jquery is really powerfull when you understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have this in something like

```
.ajax(
  // calling code here
  success: function(data, status, xhr) {
     var jqData = $(data);
     var countMap = {};
     jqData.find("Value").each(function() {
         // filter for only P1
         var jqThis = $(this);
         if(jqThis.parent().find("Name").text == "p1") {
             if(countMap[jqThis.text]) {
                 countMap[jqThix.text]++;
             } else {
                 countMap[jqThis.text] = 1;
             }
         }
     });
     // From here countMap should contain the value in Value for each p1 as a key
     // and a count of occurrences as a value
  }
 );
```